# When will patent be approved, if it's going to be?

Tags: patentability

Once the application is posted how long will it be before we find out if we have the patent?

If there are similar patents but no documentation of testing to prove it works will we be approved, as far as novelty is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

Once you file a patent, it will take at least 24 months from the day the application date is issued before you know if your patent application is granted or not. The USPTO will inform if your patent is rejected and what cause the rejection. So to avoid wasting money in a patent application, make sure you have met all the requirements for a patent grant and you have a good chance for a patent grant.

Answer (score 0):

The backlog for patents examinations are "many years", your patent attorney who have helped you preparing the filing will be able to give you a better estimate for your particular field.

Once it is examined, it will most likely be rejected with a number of objections, which at that time you will have to respond to and possible make corrections to clarify what exactly you are seeking a patent on and how that differs from the prior art the examiner have found.